# Validate single dot and space in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to validate name below conditions

1. First & last char should be alphabetic and no space in leading and trailing.
2. If there any dot then there should be a space. Name can contain at most 1 dot and 1 space.
3. Word length should be 5,20.

**Code Work:**

```
    def check(word):
        matchObj = re.match( r'^(([^ ]?)(^[a-zA-Z]).*([a-zA-Z]$)([^ ]?))$', word, re.M|re.I)
        if matchObj:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I am able to do 1st point but unable to understand how to do 2nd point. And for the 3rd point I tried `{5,20}` before the last `$` of regex but it's not working.

From the above regex I want to validate 
- Jackson 
- Dr. Jackson

and invalidate the below:
- Dr.  Jackson # two space after dot(.)
- Dr. .Jackson # contains two dots

Hope with above you got my issue.

Comment: Why not just use `len` for #3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex with lookahead assertions:

```
(?mi)^[a-z](?!(?:.*\.){2})(?!(?:.* ){2})(?!.*\.[a-z])[a-z. ]{3,18}[a-z]$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/m4k3io/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?mi)`: Enable MULTILINE and IGNORE_CASE modes
- `^`: Start
- `[a-z]`: Match a letter at start
- `(?!(?:.*\.){2})`: Negative Lookahead to assert that we don't have more than one dot
- `(?!(?:.* ){2})`: Negative Lookahead to assert that we don't have more than one space
- `(?!.*\.[a-z])`: Negative Lookahead to assert that if we have a dot then it is not followed by a letter
- `[a-z. ]{3,18}`: Match 3 to 18 of given characters to **make total length 5 to 20**
- `[a-z]`: Match a letter before end
- `$`: End

Comment: Can you please explain your answer so that future purpose I will keep this tips in mind.

Comment: How {3,18} makes 5 to 20 length. As I know it will check the length from 3 to 18. Length = 3 and length = 18 is included.

Comment: in `(?!(?:.*\.){2})` What does {2} meant?

Comment: `{3,18}` is after matching one letter at start and one at end so total it becomes `{5,20}`. Also `(?:.*\.){2}` matches any no of characters followed by dot which is in non-capturing group quantified by `{2}`  to make it match 2 dots anywhere

Comment: This regex will fail for names containing none ASCI characters like **Prof. Jürgen**. IMHO, using `\w+` instead of `[a-z]` with `UNICODE` flag would be better choice.

Comment: @HadiRj: Yes, that can be added if OP has requirement to support UNICODE names.